# Store data in Database Android

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite

i made a TextView that displayed value with multiple line
and i want to keep that value in a SQLite database. this is the code i use:

```
public void AddContact(Contact c)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();
    cv.put("nom",c.getNom());
    Scanner s = new Scanner(String.valueOf(cv));
    while (s.hasNextLine()){
        String line = s.nextLine();
        db.insert("contact",line,cv);
        
    }
```

the problem is when i save the value, the whole value is inserted into one cell. i want the value to be separated per line then inserted into a single cell for each line despite I am using Scanner method with the insertion data but it dosen't function.
is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, this line:

```
cv.put("nom",c.getNom());
```

assigns the full string of `c.getNom()` to the `ContentValues` object and this is what you insert in the table.
You must assign each row of `c.getNom()` to `cv` and insert it, one at each iteration of the `while` loop:

```
public void AddContact(Contact c) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    Scanner s = new Scanner(c.getNom());
    while (s.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = s.nextLine();
        cv.put("nom", line); 
        db.insert("contact", null, cv);
    }      
}
```

Comment: The insertion line by line  is done but in the database there are empty boxes between each element was insered

Comment: @Olfatounsii If the lines of the string are separated by `"\n\r"` then use: `if (line.trim().length() > 0) {db.insert("contact", null, cv);}` instead of just `db.insert("contact", null, cv);`